# Find values in table that only have one value

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a query that will search for fields in a database that only have one type of value. E.g. each person (`regNum`) can have up to four types of status at any one time ('`A`', '`B`', '`C`' or '`D`') and I would like to find those that only have status of '`C`'.

```
SELECT DISTINCT tbl_studentModules.regNum FROM tbl_studentModules
        LEFT JOIN tbl_student
        ON tbl_student.regNum = tbl_studentModules.regNum
        WHERE status ? 'C' AND level = $level"
```

The question mark represents where I would like a statement that would say something similar to 'is only'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT sm.regNum
FROM tbl_studentModules sm
LEFT JOIN tbl_student s ON s.regNum = sm.regNum
AND level = $level
group by sm.regnum
HAVING sum(status <> 'C') = 0
```

Comment: That's also going to find rows that have no status at all. I don't know if that's an issue, but probably should be accounted for.

Comment: Hi, all of the rows have a status so that isn't an issue at all.  This works great so thanks, I'll accept it s the answer in 10 mins when it lets me, great stuff

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest doing this with a temp table. Grab everything that doesnt have C, as such:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS t1;
CREATE TEMP TABLE t1 AS
SELECT DISTINCT tbl_studentModules.regNum 
    FROM tbl_studentModules
    LEFT JOIN tbl_student
    ON tbl_student.regNum = tbl_studentModules.regNum
    WHERE status NOT IN ('A','B','D') AND level = $level";

SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE status = 'C';
```